# Is higher weapon speed better, or lower?

Tags: starbound

Melee weapons have two stats: *Damage per swing* and *Swing speed*. The meaning of *damage per swing* is fairly obvious, but what does *swing speed* measure? Is it time/swing (so a lower value is better), or swings/time (a higher value is better)?

Comment: You also want to look at the armor penetration of it; a weapon with 4 armor penetration and 30 damage is worst than a weapon with 8 armor penetration and 17 damage, so keep an eye on that as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Higher value means more swings/shots/attacks per second, so higher value is better.

Comment: This depends ofcourse. if you have a high damage weapon with low swing speed it could be better then a weapon with faster swing speed but lower damage

Comment: @SergeBekenkamp true, but assuming all else is equal, higher swing speed is better. Also, weapons with lower swing speeds might have a better reach, but that's unaccounted for in stats (at the moment)

Comment: @SergeBekenkamp Given that weapon knockback is always the same, higher speed/lower damage is always better because it keeps mobs off you.

Answer (score 0):

Having only played Starbound for a bit, I can not answer this 100%. But, looking at its brother, Terreria, higher swing speed would be better. Usually, the swing speed is related to how many swings per second, not the other way around.